# Issue in hornetq: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid logic on buffer allocation

Tags: java, hornetq

I am using hornetq-2.0. IllegalStateException occured when my jms queue gets piled up. Below is the stack trace for the exception.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid logic on buffer allocation

```
    at org.hornetq.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.appendRecord(JournalImpl.java:2820)

    at org.hornetq.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.appendAddRecordTransactional(JournalImpl.java:968)

    at org.hornetq.core.persistence.impl.journal.JournalStorageManager.storeMessageTransactional(JournalStorageManager.java:567)

    at org.hornetq.core.postoffice.impl.PostOfficeImpl.processRoute(PostOfficeImpl.java:900)

    at org.hornetq.core.postoffice.impl.PostOfficeImpl.route(PostOfficeImpl.java:665)

    at org.hornetq.core.postoffice.impl.PostOfficeImpl.route(PostOfficeImpl.java:539)

    at org.hornetq.core.paging.impl.PagingStoreImpl.onDepage(PagingStoreImpl.java:1006)

    at org.hornetq.core.paging.impl.PagingStoreImpl.readPage(PagingStoreImpl.java:698)

    at org.hornetq.core.paging.impl.PagingStoreImpl.access$200(PagingStoreImpl.java:64)

    at org.hornetq.core.paging.impl.PagingStoreImpl$DepageRunnable.run(PagingStoreImpl.java:1181)

    at org.hornetq.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$1.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:96)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

After this error occurred the hornetq had to be restarted and the pages and journals had to be cleared.

Comment: A lot of the time, the exception by itself is not sufficient for solving a problem.  Please also include related code.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the message won't fit into the active journal file and won't fit into the next (presumably empty) journal file either. I don't know why that happens in your case. It may be a bug, it may be a very large message combined with a small journal file or you may have limited the size and number of your journal files?

Comment: The size and number of journal files has not been modified. It takes the default values and the messages are not very large compared to the journal size.

Comment: Yet you write that the queue gets piled up, so presumably there are many small messages? HornetQ 2.0 is fairly old, so  you could try upgrading if it is a bug in the product. You could also try increasing the journal sizes as the error you get is generated when a message won't fit into the journal, it might help. Finally you could provide more details - code, numbers on the number of messages received and the number still in queue etc. Good luck!